# How to gracefully fire many request to an API

Tags: java, api

I have been given a API link of the form of a URL and query string. And following is my approach,

- Query string format means that a GET request is to be fired.
- I also assume that this can be done with the `HttpURLConnection` in Java
- I have some data list that I'm retrieving from db

How would I fire for each data in list? Is a simple `for` loop not going to be enough for such  a sophisticated task?

The API link is a trivial link with query string with data from db to be appended to one at a time.

Would like to hear how you would approach this task and see if my approach lacks somewhere.

Comment: ask API authors what their expectations about the request rate are and whether the API supports bulk requests

Comment: I think a for loop is good enough if you have just a couple dozen but if you have hundreds then you might do a form of thread pool. Is there an general number of requests you are attempting to send?

Comment: Your question needs to reveal more information for us to give you a specific answer. Can the Web API process the requests async ? What is the maximum load you can send to the API ? Can requests be batched into one ? (If yes what is the max batch size ?).

Comment: API details given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933553/how-to-gracefully-fire-many-request-to-an-api/20933655?noredirect=1#comment31434646_20933655

Comment: @ns47731 : I'm new to threading. Will the Java Concurrency tutorial get me upto speed quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in doubting the simple `for` loop approach. It would be slow. The request is blocking, so you'll be waiting for the result of request 1 before firing request 2. Look into doing this asynchronously, firing multiple requests at once.

It's hard to say more without details on the API. Is it an online web service? Something internal created by another department? If it does not exist, consider asking for a version of that function that can receive multiple parameters at once, instead of having to do tons of tiny calls.

Comment: It is not a API exposed by a well known web service. It is a low end SMS service provider. Link is of the form: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/bulksms/bulksms?`query string with cell phone`

Comment: sending sms would benefit from making a bean to store all info (Msg, to number, any tracking info for logs); use a ThreadPoolExecutor to queque and async jobs. core and max threads more than 1 ... @Ahsan